# What is the difference between these two asynchronous methods?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

What's difference between this two asynchronous methods? If didn't, In which situation this two kind of methods can was different?

Thanks.

```
public async Task<int> MyMethod1Async()
{
    return 1;
}

public async Task<int> MyMethod2Async()
{
    return await new Task<int>(() => 1);
}
```

Comment: Since there is no async code, First one will not be async....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the underlying question about how async/await works is valuable but this simplified form is flawed. Even pointing to a duplicate question is hard since one of the examples isn't asynchronous.

Comment: When do you actually run the task in MyMethod2Async? You just create a new task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the two methods:

```
public async Task<int> MyMethod1Async()
{
    return 1;
}
```

This will run synchronously because there are no "await" operators in it - it just returns 1, so it's no different than if you had just done the following:

```
public int MyMethod1()
{
    return 1;
}
```

The following method is probably a better illustration of the difference between different "types" of async:

```
    public async Task<string> MyMethod1Async()
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("SomeBaseAddress");

            // This will return control to the method's caller until this gets a result from the server
            HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync("SomeURI");

            // The same as above - returns control to the method's caller until this is done
            string content = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return content;
        }
    }
```

Code like this won't necessarily spawn extra threads (unless that's how Microsoft happened to have implemented those particular library calls). Either way, await/async does *not* require the creation of additional threads; it can run asynchronously on the same thread.

My standard illustration of this fact is as follows: suppose you go a restaurant with 10 people. When the waiter comes by, the first person he asks for his order isn't ready; however, the other 9 people are. Thus, the waiter asks the other 9 people for their orders and then comes back to the original guy hoping he'll be ready to order by then. (It's definitely not the case that they'll get a second waiter to wait for the original guy to be ready to order and doing so probably wouldn't save much time anyway). That's how async/await works in many cases (the exception being that some of the Task Parallel library calls, like Thread.Run(...), actually *are* executing on other threads - in our illustration, bringing in a second waiter - so make sure you check the documentation for which is which).

The next item you list won't work because you just create the task, you don't actually do anything with it:

```
public async Task<int> MyMethod2Async()
{
    return await new Task<int>(() => 1);
}
```

I'm assuming that you actually intended to do something like the following:

```
public async Task<int> MyMethod2Async()
{
    return await Task.Run<int>(() => 1);
}
```

This will run the lambda expression in the thread pool, return control to MyMethod2Async's caller until the lambda expression has a result, and then return the value from the lambda expression once it does have a result.

To summarize, the difference is whether you're running asynchronously on the same thread (equivalent to the first guy at your table telling the waiter to come back to him after everyone else has ordered) or if you're running the task on a separate thread.

At risk of oversimplifying things a lot, CPU-bound tasks should generally be run asynchronously on a background thread. However, IO-bound tasks (or other cases where the holdup is mostly just waiting for some kind of result from an external system) can often be run asynchronously on the same thread; there won't necessarily be much of a performance improvement from putting it on a background thread vs. doing it asynchronously on the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

The first method returns an already completed task with a `Result` of `1`.

The second method returns a `Task<int>` that will never complete.